Is my electrical system messed up?
I have a 2014 Mazda CX-5 that didn’t start today (was working fine on my trip to the grocery store yday) and I tried to jump it with cables without success. My neighbor came out with a portable jump starter so I took him up on his offer. He connected it to an outlet on his house and we connected it and powered it up. I saw one spark, but not sure where it came from. Car didn’t start the first go, it did start the second go. However, when it started, engine codes p061b and p0102 came up as well as a flashing tire pressure light and TCS came on. I tried to drive it but it kept stumbling/kicking when accelerating so I stopped. I turned the car off and on again without any issue, but CEL was still on and tire pressure lights were still flashing. I’m worried that the jump start blew my circuit or messed up the electrical system some how…. I replaced the battery today with a new one but same issues and not driveable :( any insights?

So after some tinkering, looks like the MAF sensor is the issue. Ran the car snd unplugged the MAF sensor and car kept running and instead of turning off. Plan is to replace that first. Has anyone had experience with their MAF sensors failing after a jump start?

Before you change out any parts, check the voltage at the battery and ensure it is fully charged. A low battery can throw all kinds of strange codes which in the end means nothing.

What's the condition of the MAF?

The cable jump may just have been a fluke, there are many points of failure which need to be checked (the mazda engine is small, but the donor car needs good voltage and a bit of RPM, and leads need correct connection order and location). Also the "spark" from the home jump kit also seems a fluke - I frequently see a spark or two when connecting and disconnecting battery leads.

What do you mean condition of MAF? I guess I didn’t take a look at it yet, was going to tomorrow when I attempt to replace it. Is there any specific to look out for?

I’ll try to check rthe battery tomorrow, need to find my multimeter. It doubt it’s the battery? Starts fine and it’s a new battery.

It was the MAF sensor. Replaced it with an OEM part and all the codes went away immediately and car ran like it did before. Wondering if the jumpstart somehow blew out that sensor.
